# Get Post Terms of Current Post (selected taxonomy term) - How to get only the taxonomy value and not "Array ( [0] => taxonomy term )" in the frontend?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, taxonomy

I use the get_post_term code from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms. 
I can retrieve the selected taxonomy term from the current post but the displayed value looks like this: Array ( [0] => Taxonomy Term).
I only want the taxonomy term in the frontend.

`//Returns Array of Term Names for "my_taxonomy"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "names"));
print_r($term_list);`

Does someone know how to only display the selected taxonomy term?

Comment: You want the name of the Term? A Term is associated with many properties. Which component are you interested in displaying. I assume the name; e.g., Animals?

Comment: Yes, I want only the name.

Answer (score 2):

The [`wp_get_post_terms()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) returns one or more term names when you call it with `array( 'fields' => 'names' )`. So you have a few different options available to you.

Grab the first term name that was found.

```
<?php
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array('fields' => 'names'));

if ( ! empty( $term_names ) ) {
  echo $term_names[0]; // Cats
}
```

Or, you can implode the list of term names and show them in comma-delimited format.

```
<?php
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array('fields' => 'names'));

echo implode(', ', $term_names); // Cats, Pets, Animals
```

Or, you can iterate through the list and do something else.

```
<?php
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array('fields' => 'names'));

foreach( $term_names as $name ) {
    echo $name.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the taxonomy name is "animals"

```
<?php
    //This will show all the terms in taxonomy whether they have posts or not thus the "hide_empty"
    $terms = get_terms( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'animals', 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'description', 'order' => 'ASC' ));

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        // The $term is an object, so we can get the names.
        //use var_dump($term) to see other options available
        echo $name = $term->name;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with this code to show only the name, however the output is displayed in small characters so I only need to capitalize it somehow

`<?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'my_taxonomy' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->slug ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?>`